# Getting "signal 15 (Terminated), will terminate after current cmd ends" and Mongodb shutting down? Fork condition is not mentioned in config

Tags: mongodb, server, mongodb-query, mongo-shell

```
2021-06-16T08:00:01.172-0700 I CONTROL  [signalProcessingThread] got signal 15 (Terminated), will terminate after current cmd ends
2021-06-16T08:00:01.172-0700 I NETWORK  [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2021-06-16T08:00:01.172-0700 I NETWORK  [signalProcessingThread] removing socket file: /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
2021-06-16T08:00:01.172-0700 I REPL     [signalProcessingThread] shutting down replication subsystems
2021-06-16T08:00:01.172-0700 I REPL     [signalProcessingThread] Stopping replication reporter thread
2021-06-16T08:00:01.172-0700 I REPL     [signalProcessingThread] Stopping replication fetcher thread
2021-06-16T08:00:01.173-0700 I REPL     [signalProcessingThread] Stopping replication applier thread
2021-06-16T08:00:01.173-0700 I REPL     [rsSync-0] Finished oplog application
2021-06-16T08:00:02.053-0700 I REPL     [rsBackgroundSync] Stopping replication producer
2021-06-16T08:00:02.054-0700 I REPL     [signalProcessingThread] Stopping replication storage threads
```

MongoDB shell version: 2.6.10

The mongodb server is shutting down suddenly and starts working when it's restarted?